# Acquire release operation of c++11(atomic)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class atomicAcquireRelease00
{
public:
    atomicAcquireRelease00() : x(false), y(false), z(0) {}
    void run()
    {
        std::thread a(&atomicAcquireRelease00::write_x, this);
        std::thread b(&atomicAcquireRelease00::write_y, this);
        std::thread c(&atomicAcquireRelease00::read_x_then_y, this);
        std::thread d(&atomicAcquireRelease00::read_y_then_x, this);

        a.join();
        b.join();
        c.join();
        d.join();

        std::cout<<"z == "<<z.load()<<std::endl;
    }

private:
    void write_x()
    {                
        x.store(true, std::memory_order_release); //(1)
    }

    void write_y()
    {           
        y.store(true, std::memory_order_release); //(2)
    }

    void read_x_then_y()
    {            
        while(!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)); //(3)
        if(y.load(std::memory_order_acquire)){    //(4)
            ++z;
        }
    }

    void read_y_then_x()
    {           
        while(!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire));  //(5)
        if(x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)){      //(6)
            ++z;
        }

    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> x, y;
    std::atomic<int> z;
};            

int main()
{
   for(size_t i = 0; i != 50; ++i){
     atomicAcquireRelease00().run();
   }          

  return 0;
}
```

`atomicAcquireRelease00` do not respect the order when loading the value. As
far as I know, if I declared the operation store as `std::memory_order_release`
and operation load as `std::memory_order_acquire` as a pair, the operations of
load and store on the same atomic variable will synchronize, but this simple
example doesn't work as I expected.

The process base on my imagination

- case A :

  1. x set as true
  2. at (4), y.load return false, z remain zero
  3. y set as true
  4. after (6), z become one
- case B :

  1. y set as true
  2. at (6), x.load return false, z remain zero
  3. x set as true
  4. after (4), z become one
- case C :

  1. x set as true, y set as true
  2. after (4) and (6), z become 2

I can't guarantee `x` or `y` would be set to true first, but when `x` set to true, the load of `x` should be synchronized with it as well as `y,` so what kind of situation would make `z` remain zero?

Comment: For a solution, see the example "Sequentially-consistent ordering" at [cppreference: memory order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) (i.e. use `std::memory_order_seq_cst`).

Comment: Thanks, I know I can do it by std::memory_order_seq_cst.What I want to know is the reason of this unexpected result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ***exactly*** the Sample Listing 5.7 from "Concurrency In Action" by Anthony Williams.

He explains:

> In this case the assert *can* fire (just like in the relaxed-ordering case), because it’s possible for both the load of `x` and the load of `y` to read `false`. **x and y are written by different threads**, so the ordering from the release to the acquire in each case has no effect on the operations in the other threads.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get why "x and y written by different threads would make the synchronization" fail?

Comment: @StereoMatching because that's what `acquire`/`release` does: it only "works" for strictly pair-wise synchronization scenarios

Comment: The author of the book goes on to explain how `acquire`/`release` ordering semantics are valuable /at all/ then, but I'm not comfortable lecturing out of his book for more than I already did. If you don't already have it, you can buy the book at http://www.manning.com/williams/

Answer (score 2):

C/C++11 does not guarantee a total order of stores to different memory locations unless you use seq_cst.  So each thread is free to see the stores in a different order.  Acquire-release synchronization doesn't help as it is only from the thread doing the store to the thread doing the load.
If you want to play around with unit tests like this and better develop your intuition, try CDSChecker.  It is a tool that will show you all behaviors that any real implementation of C11 is likely to produce.